# Perseid Meteor Shower Viewing events near Chicago

Tags: amateur-observing, star-gazing, meteor-shower

I'm going to be in Chicago during the weekend of Aug 11th, 2018. Can you suggest any viewing parties that are not too far away?

I'm very very amateur. I don't really know too much about astronomy, but do like being around people that do.

Please post any events that you know of like this one that was one about an hour away at Indiana Dunes State Park. https://www.trippy.com/a/5b65a86ae4b0e99fd1765e1b/507c527fe4b0c31db879944f

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Astronomical League's [list of astronomy clubs](https://www.astroleague.org/societies/IL) leads to these opportunities:

- The [Skokie Valley Astronomers](http://www.skokievalleyastronomers.org/) have a meeting at the [Ryerson Forest Preserve](https://www.lcfpd.org/ryerson/welcome-center/) in Riverwoods on Friday the 10th.
- Some [Naperville Astronomical Association](http://www.stargazing.net/naa/index.shtml) members will be at a [stargazing picnic at Cantigny Park](https://cantigny.org/event/french-picnic-stars/) in Wheaton on Saturday the 11th.

Like most meteor showers, the Perseids produce more meteors in the early morning, but there should be some in the late evening.

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck. Please consider upvoting or accepting this answer.

Comment: hi. I did upvote it, but I don't have enough rep pts for it to show up. If it doesn't show up after my rep gets bigger, I'll come back and give youthe props you deserve